# Stackstorm 2.7 webhook "AccessRefused: 403" error

Tags: python, webhooks

I have successfully created a webhook in stackstorm and it is visible in the webhook lists.

```
 [centos@ip- ~]$ sudo st2 webhook list
 +------------+------------------+-------------+
 | url        | type             | description |
 +------------+------------------+-------------+
 | wfcreation | core.st2.webhook |             |
 +------------+------------------+-------------+
 [centos@ip- ~]$
```

I triggered the webhook giving a payload and setting proper headers using stackstorm api key. The webhook gets triggered and returns with a status code of 200. But the underlying stackstorm workflow fails giving the below error.

```
{
  "traceback": "  File \"/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/st2actions/container/base.py\", line 119, in _do_run
    (status, result, context) = runner.run(action_params)
  File \"/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/retrying.py\", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File \"/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/retrying.py\", line 206, in call
    return attempt.get(self._wrap_exception)
  File \"/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/retrying.py\", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File \"/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/retrying.py\", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File \"/opt/stackstorm/runners/mistral_v2/mistral_v2/mistral_v2.py\", line 247, in run
    result = self.start_workflow(action_parameters=action_parameters)
  File \"/opt/stackstorm/runners/mistral_v2/mistral_v2/mistral_v2.py\", line 284, in start_workflow
    **options)
  File \"/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mistralclient/api/v2/executions.py\", line 65, in create
    return self._create('/executions', data)
  File \"/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mistralclient/api/base.py\", line 100, in _create
    self._raise_api_exception(resp)
  File \"/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mistralclient/api/base.py\", line 160, in _raise_api_exception
    error_message=error_data)
",
  "error": "AccessRefused: 403"
}
```

The official stakstorm documentation does not have any reference of troubleshooting this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am blocked on this right now.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to figure out the problem was with the mistral-server service running on the stackstorm host.

The problem was that the mistral-server service was not able to connect to rabbitmq service due to a misconfiguration during stackstorm installation.But the misleading error message "AccessRefused: 403" did not pin point towards an issue with rabbitmq connection issue.

So here is what I found in the logs.

The error message in the mistral logs (/var/log/mistral/):

```
2018-06-25 15:30:19.309 10767 ERROR oslo_service.service AccessRefused: (0,0): (403) ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.
```

On digging the rabbitmq logs (/var/log/rabbitmq/):

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 25-Jun-2018::16:34:23 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.5118.0> (127.0.0.1:41248 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
{handshake_error,starting,0,
             {amqp_error,access_refused,
                         "AMQPLAIN login refused: user 'st2' - invalid credentials",
                         'connection.start_ok'}}
```

Clearly the st2 user credentials were wrongly configured during installation and that led to this whole issue.

Hope this helps somebody in future.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that could cause this is not having NGinx configured, and in that case the system wants you to use local ports. Here's an example that might help you: https://github.com/StackStorm/st2/tree/master/conf/st2.conf.sample and here's the [nginx config](https://docs.stackstorm.com/install/config/config.html#nginx-and-wsgi).